# Way to include one .hgignore file in another

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

Is there any way to include one `.hgignore` file in another?

e.g., say I have a common `.hgignore` file in a Mercurial subrepository (named `hg-common`) that ignores files like `desktop.ini` & `.DS_Store`, and I want to include that file in every project that I create.  In my `.hgignore` of my `project1` repo, I want to do something like:

```
syntax: include hg-common/.hgignore
```

with `syntax: include` being my imaginary syntax for including the specified file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the correct syntax:

```
include:hg-common/.hgignore
```

Comment: Why not use `~/.hgignore_global`?

Comment: @aflp91 because, I want the ignores in a subrepo to force all users of the repo to ignore the same files.

Answer (score 3):

You can use either `include` or `subinclude`:

```
include:hg-common/.hgignore
subinclude:hg-common/.hgignore
```

The difference is that `subinclude` confines its effect to the hg-common directory, whereas `include` applies the patterns globally.